# WKWebView did not load the url

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I have a tabbar to control my WKWebView's load url,

At first i give the WKWebView a defult url request.

But when I click the other item it pass the code, but did not load the special url:

[image]

My code is below, the tabbar is created by storyboard:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tabBar: UITabBar!
    var dataSources: Array = ["https://www.baidu.com", "https://www.sougou.com", "https://www.hao123.com"]

    lazy var wkWebView:WKWebView = {

        let rect:CGRect = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: self.view.bounds.size.height - 44)

        let wkWebView:WKWebView = WKWebView.init(frame: rect)

        return wkWebView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // 1.wkwebview
        self.view.addSubview(self.wkWebView)
        wkWebView.load(URLRequest.init(url: URL.init(string: dataSources[0])!))
        tabBar.delegate = self

        tabBar.selectedItem = tabBar.items?.first
    }

    // MARK: tabbar delegate
    func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {

        if item.tag == 101 {

            wkWebView.load(URLRequest.init(url: URL.init(string: dataSources[0])!))
        }else if item.tag == 102 {
            wkWebView.load(URLRequest.init(url: URL.init(string: dataSources[1])!))
        }else {
            wkWebView.load(URLRequest.init(url: URL.init(string: dataSources[2])!))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would assume it's because those other URL's you're loading are `http://`, and without exceptions being added to your plist Apple blocks cleartext requests.

Comment: @Chris, oh, soory about it, ignore it, nomatter it is https, or http, it will not load.